# Python: replace html img src after extraction with xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath

I extract some html code from this [site](http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/11giannakopoulos.html), now i can see all the code that i scrape exept the images, due to their incorrect src.

```
#!C:/Python27/python
from lxml import etree
import requests

q = "http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/11giannakopoulos.html"
page = requests.get(q)
tree = etree.HTML(page.text)
element = tree.xpath('./body/form/table[3]/tr/td/table[5]')
content = etree.tostring(element[0])
print "Content-type: text\n\n"
print content.strip()
```

Now i read the correct img src (what i want) and put this in an array:

```
pic=[]
link = q.rsplit("/",1)
images = tree.xpath("//img/@src")
for i in images:
    if i.find('.gif') == -1:
        pic.append(link[0]+"/"+i)
```

How can i replace the src scraped with the src in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you are looking for.

```
link = q.rsplit("/",1)
images = tree.xpath("//img")

for idx, image in enumerate(images):
    if '.gif' not in image.attrib['src']:
        images[idx].attrib['src'] = link[0]+'/'+image.attrib['src']

for image in images:
    print image.attrib['src']
```

It loops through each of the images selected and if `'.gif'` is not in the image `src` attribute, it updates the `src` attribute to the PNG/JPG path you specified.

**Output**

```
../../../img2/space.gif
../../../img2/search2.gif
../../../img2/space.gif
../../../img2/D-Lib-blocks.gif
../../../img2/transparent.gif
../../../img2/magazine.gif
../../../img2/transparent.gif
../../../img2/transparent.gif
../../../img2/space.gif
../../../img2/space.gif
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/giann-formula1.png
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/giann-fig1-sm.png
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/giann-fig2.png
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/giann-fig3.png
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/giann-fig4.png
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/giannakopoulos.jpg
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/foufoulas.jpg
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/stamatogiannakis.png
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/dimitropoulos.jpg
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/manola.jpg
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/ioannidis.png
../../../img2/transparent.gif
```